# how to create list with index in name in python

Tags: python, list, indexing

I it possible in python to create a set of lists with index i in the name?

```
for i in range(0,5):
    list_i = []  # here i should change according to index i
```

I would like to create 5 lists with names: 
list_0, list_1 ... _list_4 and the append something to these lists.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do variable variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-do-variable-variables-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a dictionary of lists.

```
results_dict = {}
for i in range(5):
    results_dict[i] = []
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot, so it is only possible with dictionary ... I thought that there's another way how to create a list from a string maybe ...

Comment: There are some super hacky methods to use dynamic variable names, but there's no reason to use them. It's much easier/readable to just use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be very straightforward, but I don't call this super hacky though. It is quite useful in some cases to use **dynamic naming**.

```
for i in range(5):
    vars()['list_%d'%i] = i

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
print(list_3)
print(list_4)
```

**List Version**

```
for i in range(5):
    vars()['list_%d'%i] = [i, i+1]

print(list_1)
print(list_2)
print(list_3)
print(list_4)
```

Comment: Does this work if `vars()['list_%d' %i] = []`? In other words, initializing to an empty list like the OP's question?